# requests with extensions throwing 404 in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

All my requests ending with any extension like .jpg, .gif are throwing 404. The content for these requests are served from database. It works if i append a trailing backslash to the request.

http://www.example.com/1.jpg **doesn't work**

http://www.example.com/1.jpg/ **Works**

i have runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests set to true but i think it's not used in 7.5.

This also work perfectly fine in my box but doesn't in a test box.

Answer (score 0):

I edited my web.config and added the following to get .json to work.

```
<handlers>
  ...
  <add name="MyJsonHandler" path="*.json" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
```

You can do this manually in your web.config or use IIS to manage it in the HTTP Handlers for the web site you are configuring.